# Recuperar dados de uma consulta Linq SQL com Join

Tags: .net, linq

Na camada de apresentação chamo um método `consLaboratorio` que está em um *namespace* separado onde é realizado todo o acesso aos dados.
Este método retorna um objeto `MiddleOneReturn`  com: codigoErro (0-se rodou sem erros) e o resultado da execução ("object[]").
Recupero os dados através do seguinte *Cast*: `((List<Laboratorio>)(md.Mensagem[0])).ToList();`, onde `Laboratorio` se refere à classe mapeada via entity framework.

```
EstudoDotNetNegocio objEstudoDotNet = new EstudoDotNetNegocio();
MiddleOneReturn md = new MiddleOneReturn();
md = objEstudoDotNet.consLaboratorio(1);
if (md.CodigoErro == 0)
{
    var local = ((List<Laboratorio>)(md.Mensagem[0])).ToList();
    string idLaboratorio = local.FirstOrDefault().IdLaboratorio.ToString();
    string nomeLaboratorio = local.FirstOrDefault().NmLaboratorio.ToString();
}
```

`MiddleOneReturn` fica em um *namespace* separado com outros métodos utilitários. É usado para trafegar dados entre as camadas e tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class MiddleOneReturn
{
    public MiddleOneReturn() { }
    public MiddleOneReturn(int codigo, params object[] mensagem) {
        CodigoErro = codigo;
        Mensagem = mensagem;
    }
    public int CodigoErro { get; set; }
    public object[] Mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

O método `consLaboratorio` fica em um *namespace* com todos os outros métodos de acesso a dados via Linq.

```
public MiddleOneReturn consLaboratorio(Int64 IdLaboratorio)
{
    using (BDEntities db = new BDEntities())
    {
        var laboratorio = db.Laboratorio.Where(v => v.IdLaboratorio.Equals(IdLaboratorio)).ToList();
        MiddleOneReturn md = new MiddleOneReturn();
        md.CodigoErro = 0;
        md.Mensagem = new object[] { laboratorio };
        return md;
    }
}
```

O problema é quando executo um *join* com retorno que pertença a duas tabelas distintas como o exemplo abaixo:

```
public MiddleOneReturn consLaboratorioCidade(Int64 IdLaboratorio)
{
    using (BDEntities db = new BDEntities())
    {
        var laboratorio = (from l in db.Laboratorio
                           join c in db.Cidade on l.IdLaboratorio equals c.IdCidade into l_join_c
                           from c in l_join_c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where l.IdLaboratorio == IdLaboratorio
                            select new
                            {
                                l.IdLaboratorio,
                                l.NmLaboratorio,
                                c.NmCidade
                            }).ToList();
        MiddleOneReturn md = new MiddleOneReturn();
        md.CodigoErro = 0;
        md.Mensagem = new object[] { laboratorio };
        return md;
    }
}
```

No modelo, gerado a partir do banco de dados, não existe uma classe com os campos retornados ao executar o comando acima, portanto não é possível efetuar o *Cast*.

O conteúdo retornado é:

```
md.Mensagem[0]
Count = 1
    [0]: { IdLaboratorio = 1, NmLaboratorio = "Laboratório 1", NmCidade = "Campinas" }
```

Como solucionar este problema?

Comment: Você poderia criar uma classe "Lab" com os campos `IdLaboratorio`, `NmLaboratorio` e `NmCidade`...

Comment: @ Andre Figueiredo Foi o caminho que tentei seguir "var local = ((List<LaboratorioCidade>)(md.Mensagem[0])).ToList();" só retorna erro: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`3[System.Int64,System.String,System.String]]'
  no tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EstudoDotNet.LaboratorioCidade]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você não define o tipo de retorno de sua query, ela é tipada como Tipo Anônimo. No caso, você está colocando-a numa variável `object` para podê-la retornar do método. Porém, essa variável `object` não vai poder ser convertida para o tipo `List<Laboratorio>`. Mas você pode fazer por Linq:

```
var local = from x in md.Mensagem[0] select new {
    l.IdLaboratorio,
    l.NmLaboratorio,
    c.NmCidade
}
```

Visando uma melhor prática de programação, você pode tipar o retorno da query numa Classe própria:

```
public class LaboratorioCidade {
    public int IdLaboratorio {get;set;}
    public string NmLaboratorio {get;set;}
    public string NmCidade {get;set;}

    public LaboratorioCidade(){}
    public LaboratorioCidade(int idLaboratorio, string NmLaboratorio, string NmCidade){
        IdLaboratorio = idLaboratorio;
        NmLaboratorio = NmLaboratorio;
        NmCidade = NmCidade;
    }
}
```

Consulta "tipando" na sua classe:

```
                where l.IdLaboratorio == IdLaboratorio
                select new LaboratorioCidade
                {
                    IdLaboratorio = l.IdLaboratorio,
                    NmLaboratorio = l.NmLaboratorio,
                    NmCidade = c.NmCidade
                }).ToList();
```

(outra abordagem chamando o construtor com parâmetros):

```
var queryLocal = (from x in db.Tabela
                  where x.param == true
                  select new LaboratorioCidade {
                      l.IdLaboratorio,
                      l.NmLaboratorio,
                      c.NmCidade
                  }).ToList();

var queryTipada = from x in queryLocal
                  select new LaboratorioCidade(x.IdLaboratorio, x.NmLaboratorio, x.NmCidade);
```

Finalmente, chama a função:

```
md = objEstudoDotNet.consLaboratorio(1);
if (md.CodigoErro == 0)
{
    // pode trocar "var" por List<LaboratorioCidade>, se preferir
    var local = md.Mensagem[0].FirstOrDefault(); 
    string idLaboratorio = local.IdLaboratorio.ToString();
    string nomeLaboratorio = local.NmLaboratorio;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou. Usei a primeira solução: consulta "tipando" na classe. Testarei as outras sugestões. Agora na classe LaboratorioCidade na linha "NmLaboratorio = NmLaboratorio" esta aparecendo o warning "Assignment made to same variable; did you mean to assign something else?". Não afeta a execução, mas porque?

Answer (score 1):

Ao executar select new {} na sua consulta com EntityFramework, você está criando um AnonymousType. Infelizmente não é possível fazer cast de um Anonymous type para um tipo definido (Laboratorio). A solução para o seu problema pode ser muitas, a definição de um novo tipo, a implementação de um extension method de Cast ou o uso de uma função de cast entre tipos dinamicos.

De uma olhada neste post [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type) para entender melhor!

Comment: vou ler o conteúdo do link.

Comment: Teria um abordagem mais indicada para trafegar os dados entre as camadas do que este "MiddleOneReturn" que estou usando.

Comment: Eu uso um generic repository para expor as entidades,  o código fica reutilizável e permite certa flexibilidade nos filtros para outros objetos que aplicam regras de negócio.  Repository e services!